# Mulesoft database connector error on array list

Tags: database, mule

I am very new to mule so please bear with me. I am having an issue in  evaluating the mule expression going into the DB connector. While debugging, I noticed that my expression is having null values, hence caused the error. I am expecting a map result object so I can plug it in to the DB connector(SQL SERVER).

When mule executes this command, I am getting a null value

```
#[payload['FULLDATE']]
```

But Im getting results with

```
#[payload[0].FULLDATE]
```

Can you gurus shed some light on this one?

This is my full SQL statement

```
insert into [AWH_PrjPathFinder].[dbo].[ws_balesDataExt] values ('#[payload['FULLDATE']]', '#[payload.BROKER = ( payload['BROKER'] == null) ? '' : payload.BROKER.toString()]', '#[payload.CENTER = ( payload['CENTER'] == null) ? '' : payload.CENTER.toString()]', '#[payload.DATATYPE = ( payload['DATATYPE'] == null) ? '' : payload.DATATYPE.toString()]','#[payload.COTTONORG = ( payload['COTTONORG'] == null) ? '' : payload.COTTONORG.toString()]',#[payload['UNIT']],'#[payload.dateDataEnteredInAGDB']')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the for each scope within which you should have your DB endpoint.

If you have 100 elements in the list then there might be a performance hit.

I would suggest you to use a stored procedure which can accept list of values that you send and insert in the DB and send a response back .

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

Your payload is an array, so I think you will need to loop trough it with the "For Each" scope and insert every record.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check your return object type in debug mode and then evaluate the same using expression evaluator (small icon{x+y/2} available in right side of debugger.